# How to print the distance between strings in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print the distance between Strings in a list.

For example, if my list contains like below, I would like to know the distance from `Deer` to `Crazy`, but `Deer` can be anywhere in the list and `Crazy` can come before or after the `Deer` in the list.

```
['black', 'white', 'Deer', 'Blue', 'More', 'Crazy']
```

Comment: Is there a possibility of duplicates or elements are unique in your list  ?

Comment: Yep, Elements will be unique....Appreciate your help. It worked!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`list.index()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) method:

```
>>> my_list = ['black', 'white', 'Deer', 'Blue', 'More', 'Crazy']
>>> abs(my_list.index('Deer') - my_list.index('Crazy'))
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to print number of elements better your strings?

If yes I think the solution is: `print(list.index(element1)-list.index(element2))`

In your case it is :`print(list.index("Deer")-list.index("Crazy"))`

Comment: I just gave an idea .. now this is correct (after editing).

Comment: @saibhaskar In this case it is exactly the same as the accepted answer.

Comment: Yeah. But when I submitted the answer there was no response for this question. May be the answers didn't load.

Answer (score -3):

Try this code:

```
myList=['black', 'white', 'Deer', 'Blue', 'More', 'Crazy']

idx1=0
idx2=0 

if 'Deer' in myList:
    idx1=myList.index('Deer')

if 'Crazy' in myList:
    idx2=myList.index('Crazy')


print('differnce is {}'.format(idx2-idx1))
```